# Incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)

Tags: ios, fastlane

I am using fastlane to for ios deployment to hockey and I wrote like this.

```
 hockey_ver = String(latest_hockeyapp_version_number(
          api_token: '',
          app_name: '',
          ))

  increment_version_number({
        version_number: hockey_ver
    })
  increment_build_number({
    build_number: hockey_ver
  })
```

But I got error like this. How shall I do?

> /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:120:in
>   gsub': [!] incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with
>   ASCII-8BIT string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError) from
>   /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:120:injson'
>   from
>   /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:140:in
>   parse_supported_format' from
>   /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:105:inparse' from
>   /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:67:in
>   call' from
>   /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/request.rb:383:inparse_response'
>   from
>   /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/request.rb:351:in
>   block in handle_response' from
>   /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/response.rb:25:inparsed_response'
>   from
>   /Users/khantthulinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/httparty-0.15.2/lib/httparty/response.rb:88:in
>   method_missing' from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade your httparty gem to 0.14 version:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/533